# Movie Database java error

Tags: java

So I need to make a movie database using java that has the attributes name, rating, director, year and gross.The program must also Add a movie, Remove a movie by title, Sort movie by Title, Sort movie by Rating, Sort movie by Box Office Gross, Show movies by a director, Print to a database file (you may define your own protocol) and Read from a database file. I run into an error with `ArrayList <Movie>`it says the it can not be resolved to a type thus giving me errors whenever Movie is called on.

Here is the chunk that is giving the error

```
ArrayList<Movie> movieDB = new ArrayList<Movie>();
int choice;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String mvname, director, fileName;
int year;    
double rating, gross;
```

here is the code I have so far

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MovieDatabase 
{
     public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception
     {
          ArrayList<Movie> movieDB = new ArrayList<Movie>();
          int choice;

          Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
          String mvname,director,fileName;
          int year;    
          double rating,gross;
          while(true)
          {
              //menu
              System.out.println("1.Add a movie\n2.Remove a moive\n3.Sort movie by Title\n4.Sort movie by Rating");
              System.out.println("5.Sort movie by Box office Gross\n6.Show movies by a director");
              System.out.print("7.Print to a database file\n8.Read from a database file\n9.exit: ");
              choice=input.nextInt();

              switch(choice)
              {
                   case 1: System.out.println("Enter movie name: ");
                             mvname=input.next();
                             System.out.println("Enter year: ");
                             year=input.nextInt();
                             System.out.println("Enter Director name: ");
                             director=input.next();
                             System.out.println("Enter movie rating: ");
                             rating=input.nextDouble();
                             System.out.println("Enter Box Office Gross: ");

                             gross=input.nextDouble();
                             //add new moive object ot movie data base
                             movieDB.add(new Movie(mvname,year,rating,director,gross));
                             break;

                   case 2:   System.out.println("Enter movie title: ");
                             mvname=input.next();
                             //remove specified movie object by title
                             for(Movie m:movieDB)
                             {
                                  if(mvname.equals(m.getMovie_name()))
                                  {
                                      movieDB.remove(m);
                                  }
                             }
                             break;

                   case 3: //Sort the movie data records by movie title
                             Collections.sort(movieDB,Movie.titleComparator);
                             System.out.println("After sorting by title");
                             for(Movie m:movieDB)
                             {
                                  System.out.println(m.toString());
                             }
                             break;

                   case 4: //Sort the movie data records by movie rating
                             Collections.sort(movieDB,Movie.rateComparator);
                             System.out.println("After sorting by rating");
                             for(Movie m:movieDB)
                             {
                                  System.out.println(m.toString());
                             }
                             break;

                   case 5: //Sort the movie data records by movie gross
                             Collections.sort(movieDB,Movie.grossComparator);
                             System.out.println("After sorting by gross");
                             for(Movie m:movieDB)
                             {
                                  System.out.println(m.toString());
                             }
                             break;

                   case 6: //display movies by director name
                             System.out.println("Enter Director name: ");
                             director=input.next();
                             for(Movie m:movieDB)
                             {
                                  if(director.equals(m.getMovie_Director()))
                                  {
                                      System.out.println(m.toString());
                                  }
                             }
                             break;

                   case 7: //print movie data records to a text file
                             System.out.println("Enter File name: ");
                             fileName=input.next();
                             FileWriter fWriter = null;
                             BufferedWriter writer = null;
                             fWriter = new FileWriter(fileName+".txt",true);
                             writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
                             for(Movie m:movieDB)
                             {
                                  writer.write(m.toString());
                                  System.out.println(m.toString());
                             }
                             break;

                   case 8:
                             //read movie data records from a text file
                             System.out.println("Enter File name: ");
                             fileName=input.next();
                             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName+".txt"));
                             String line;
                             while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                             {
                                  System.out.println(line);
                                  String lines[]=line.split(" ");
                                  mvname=lines[0];
                                  year=Integer.parseInt(lines[1]);
                                  rating=Double.parseDouble(lines[2]);
                                  director=lines[3];
                                  gross=Double.parseDouble(lines[4]);
                                  movieDB.add(new Movie(mvname,year,rating,director,gross));
                             }
                             br.close();

                             break;

                   case 9:System.exit(1);
                   default: System.out.println("Wrong Choice!");
              }
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: please format your code, this is horrible to read. Also why did you add a JavaScript tag?

Comment: Could it possibly be that you have no Movie class or that the Movie class has not been imported?

Comment: Why do you import  `java.awt.List` but not `java.util.ArrayList`?

Comment: could you post the `Movie` class as well. If its that big , paste only its definition. Also when your saying *I run into an error with ...* how exactly are you compiling and running this main method?

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled the class name Movie below

```
ArrayList<Movie> movieDB = new ArrayList<Moive>();
```

Try this and let us know if it still fails with the error.

Comment: Where is your Movie class ? Is it in the same package ?

Comment: I just wrote a movie class and tried to extend it to moviedatabase but that didn't fix it assuming I did it right